# Which blocks are these with small round knobs?

Tags: piece-information, set-identification, clone-brands

I have few blocks remaining from the block set I got as a kid. It's not LEGO bricks, but I also couldn't find which block type are these and who is making them. Does anyone knows from looking the images who is making these and if they are still produced so I can buy them.

Sorry if this is not right place to ask. Maybe you could point me to other place where I can ask.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I saw these before, trying to find the name...

Comment: Can't find them >:(

Comment: there is a logo on last one, I tried google image search but it doesn't work

Comment: I have seen this logo being used by Märklin, a German producer for model trains, for special reseller products (https://www.mhi-portal.eu). But as far as I know they never produced such bricks.

Comment: Usually these questions are answered within hours on this site so it fun to see a real challenge come along.  Thanks for the extra pictures.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is Marklin plus,
a building system by Marklin which ran from 1973 till the end of the seventies

[image]

[image]

also see http://www.metallbaukasten.de/marklin/plus.html

thanks to the comment of Jan Windemuth for pointing me to Marklin

Comment: Nice find. Didn't know they actually built something like LEGO.